# Date Comparison always returns false no matter which operator used

Tags: javascript, date

I'm pulling my hair out a little here. I understand that an == comparison will always return false between two date objects. But really can't understand why this code returns false every time regardless which way round I set the operator.

```
      var prevWeek         = response.prevWeek  // The date to compare.
      ,   pickedDate       = prevWeek.split("-");


      var pickedDate = new Date(pickedDate[0], pickedDate[1], pickedDate[2]);
      var todaysDate = new Date();
      console.log(pickedDate); // logs Thu Apr 17 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT)
      console.log(todaysDate); // logs Fri Nov 15 2013 18:30:13 GMT+0000 (GMT)

      var compareValueOf = pickedDate.valueOf() < todaysDate.valueOf();
      console.log(compare); // always returns false


      var compare2 = pickedDate < todaysDate;
      console.log(compare2); // always returns false
      var compare3 = pickedDate.getTime() < todaysDate.getTime();
      console.log(compare3); // always returns false
```

Comment: Is it a typo? You assign a value to `compareValueOf` but write out the value of `compare`.

Comment: 2014 is not smaller than 2013. It should be false. Also, I notice that you do `new Date(pickedDate[0], pickedDate[1], pickedDate[2])`. Are you aware that the month is 0-11, not 1-12?

Comment: Also, `getTime()` and `valueOf()` gives the same value in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if pickedDate is set in 2014, and todaysDate in 2013, there is no way pickedDate can be smaller than todaysDate.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, it's actually a bug in the higher level system causing the calendar to render as a loop.

Answer (score 2):

that's because the picedDate IS smaller than the todaysDate (2014 > 2013, not the other way around) ;)

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of problems with your code.

```
var prevWeek         = response.prevWeek  // The date to compare.
,   pickedDate       = prevWeek.split("-");
```

I assume `respone.prevWeek` is a human readable string, like '2013-03-17' for the 17:th of march 2013. When you create a new date object you get the 17:th of april 2013 because the Date-object expects to get the month in 0-11 instead of 1-12. (The year is ok, and so is the day)

```
  var pickedDate = new Date(pickedDate[0], pickedDate[1], pickedDate[2]);

  var todaysDate = new Date();
  console.log(pickedDate); // logs Thu Apr 17 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT)
  console.log(todaysDate); // logs Fri Nov 15 2013 18:30:13 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

Notice that you now have a time in pickedDate as 2014-04-18 00:00:00.000  (including microseconds) and in todaysDate 2013-11-15 18:30:13.324 (including microseconds, the exact value is not know so I made it up)

```
  var compareValueOf = pickedDate.valueOf() < todaysDate.valueOf();
  console.log(compare); // always returns false
```

Above you assign the value into `compareValueOf` but logs the value of `compare`. But even if you did log the right variable you should get `false` since a date in 2014 isn't less than a date in 2013.

```
  var compare2 = pickedDate < todaysDate;
  console.log(compare2); // always returns false
```

Another way to compare date objects, that is ok to use. But once again you get `false` since you are asking if a date in 2014 is less than a date in 2013. It isn't.

```
  var compare3 = pickedDate.getTime() < todaysDate.getTime();
  console.log(compare3); // always returns false
```

Another compare that is exactly like the one above where you use `.valueOf()` since `getTime()` gives the exact same value (number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC). And once again you get `false` since the picked date is in the future.

If you only want to compare the date-part you could make sure that the time-part of `todaysDate` is zero by running `todaysDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);`. Notice that there are 4 parameters: hours, minutes, seconds and microseconds.